editing .css class in javascript
I have a style.css file having listitem-style class as


.a_suggetion_ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3DAE1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }



I need to edit border-bottom: 1px solid #D3DAE1; part of .css class in javascript with new value as border-bottom: 0px solid #D3DAE1
My javascript is having unordered list as


<ul class="a_suggetion_ul" id="a_suggetion_ul"><li><a onclick="SubCatSearchItemClick('accordion-item_1')"> Where can I find the count of cases in WIP?</a></li></ul>




Do you mean changing the border via js? You don't need to edit the class, you can apply another class or set the borderBottom property with js. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Why can't you just edit the .css file by hand?

cant edit by hand bcoz the li is the result of search box, and I have to remove the bottom border if the search result returns only one item.

Then you shouldn't edit the css code dynamically either. Rather you should apply a different (or additional) class to the element depending on the number of search results.

Or really you should just put the border in a separate declaration using the .a_suggestion_ul li:not(:last-child) { … } selector

Just add another CSS class that overrides the original, and then apply that class with JS.


function SubCatSearchItemClick(){
 document
   .querySelector('#a_suggetion_ul')
   .classList.add('remove-bottom-border');
}
.a_suggetion_ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D3DAE1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.remove-bottom-border li { 
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
<ul class="a_suggetion_ul" id="a_suggetion_ul">
  <li><a onclick="SubCatSearchItemClick('accordion-item_1')"> Where can I find the count of cases in WIP?</a></li>
</ul>



